# Как вывести http аргументы в bash скрипт на nginx

Tags: http, bash, nginx, lua

Есть кусок конфига `nginx`

```
server {

location /lua {
 content_by_lua '
 os.execute("/opt/test/script.sh")';
}
```

дальше хочу из http строки сделать разбивку по компонентам.

```
URI=="http://127.0.0.1/lua?&arg1=123&arg2=456"
```

Как правильно написать скрипт, чтобы на выходе иметь значения `arg1` и `arg2` и можно было ими оперировать? Возможно надо как-то правильно отдаль аргументы из `lua`?

Я вижу это как-то примерно так:

```
script.sh
_______________________

URI=="http://127.0.0.1/lua?&arg1=123&arg2=456"

echo $arg1 >> /tmp/test
echo "$arg2" >> /tmp/test
_______________________
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

часть конфига nginx

location /test {
          content_by_lua_file "/opt/test/script.lua";
     }

Часть конфига скрипта - для вытаскивания данных из http строки:

local arg1 = ngx.var.arg_arg1
local arg2 = ngx.var.arg_arg2
      os.execute("echo ".. arg1 .." >> /tmp/test")
      os.execute("echo ".. arg2 .." >> /tmp/test")

Answer (score 2):

[Тут](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/) примеры есть. GET параметры у nginx [доступны из переменных](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) `$arg_{имя_параметра}`. В вашем примере они будут `$arg_arg1` и `$arg_arg2`. Что-то типа:

```
location /nginx_var {
    default_type 'text/plain';

    content_by_lua "os.execute('/opt/test/script.sh ' .. ngx.var['arg_arg1'] .. ' ' .. ngx.var['arg_arg2'])";
}
```